# Django loose coupling in apps

Tags: django, loose-coupling

I'm trying to code an application that can work for several projects. I'm facing a problem that I have always to specify the name of the project when I do the imports like doing `import some_project_name.models`  inside my app, how can I overcome this coupling so that I can use the app in several projects?

Comment: Are you asking how to move an app out of a project into a common directory?

Comment: I want my app to be project agnostic, works for any project.

Answer (score 3):

1. Move the app to a common directory, outside of any project.
2. Each project's `PYTHONPATH` must then include this common directory.